# Margins and adding data to layout in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: layouts, arcgis-pro

Just starting out with Pro trying to put together a simple map. Is there a way to add printer margins in a layout?

Also I'm confused on how to import my data into the layout itself. I have it in another active window.

Comment: Please remember that there should be only one question per question, as per the [Tour].

Answer (score 2):

Each layout document within the ArcGIS pro is separate from any map frames, unlike ArcGIS. This is actually a nice feature when you get used to it.

To show your data in a layout, you first need to add and setup a Map. Then within the layout, on the Insert ribbon add that Map frame to the layout.

All of the layer settings (symbolization, etc) are stored within the Map, not the layout. You can add a single Map multiple times, or you can add multiple maps.
This is handy for showing the same area symbolized different ways. You can even link the zoom and extent for the frames together for this purpose.

I don't see anything for the printer margins, although in theory you can create whatever margins you want by simply leaving extra space in the layout.

Comment: So what I'm confused about then is if want to switch between a layout view and data view for same data the symbology would not be the same then. Would it update accordingly between views? Do they have to be linked for this to occur?

Comment: @Paul There isn't a 'view' within ArcGIS Pro like that. The Map is basically the 'data' view and the Layout is of course the layout view. Once you've added a Map to a Layout, any changes to the Map are reflected in the Layout. If you add data to one Map, it won't effect any other maps (even if they are linked).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful feedback. There is somewhat of a learning curve with Pro.

Answer (score 2):

If, by printer margins, you mean the Rulers as indicated by the red arrow in the picture below, then you need to be on the LAYOUT tab with the MAP FRAME TOOLS visible.  Then there is a Rulers checkbox that you can mark.

[image]